# Equivalente italiano del proverbio piemontese sulla cattiva lavandaia

Tags: proverbs

Mi è capitato qualche volta di sentire alcuni amici piemontesi usare il proverbio dialettale *"La cativa lavandera a treuva mai la bona pèra"*, che tradotto significa *"Una cattiva lavandaia non trova mai la pietra adatta"*, per stigmatizzare alcune situazioni in campo lavorativo in cui un lavoratore trovava pretesti nei difetti degli strumenti di lavoro per non compiere quanto doveva.

Recentemente mi è capitato di voler usare lo stesso proverbio in una certa situazione, ma, non sapendo pronunciare il piemontese, mi sono astenuto. Non mi è venuto in mente un equivalente italiano della stessa efficacia. Sapreste suggerirmi un detto o un proverbio analogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A buona lavandaia non mancò mai pietra** (su cui lavare)

- La cativa lavandera treuva mai la bona pera (Piemonte)
- A bona lavandara 'on manca petra (Calabria)
- A la bbòna lavannare nin à mangate me' la prète (Abruzzo)
- A 'na bona lavannara nu'jamancò mai pietra (Lazio)

**A cattivo lavoratore ogni zappa dà dolore.**
**A buon cavalier non manca lancia.**

*Fonte: [Dizionario dei proverbi italiani e dialettali](https://books.google.se/books?id=vXlfAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT12#v=onepage&q&f=false) di Riccardo Schwamenthal, Michele L. Straniero*

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, mi pare che "A cattivo lavoratore ogni zappa dà dolore" sia quello che più si avvicina, in quanto gli altri indicano la situazione opposta. Anche questo proverbio però non è del tutto analogo, perché il dolore provocato dall'attrezzo è un buon motivo per lamentarsi dopo aver lavorato, magari anche poco e male, mentre non trovare una pietra adatta può essere una scusa più valida per non lavorare affatto.

Comment: Ho sentito usare, ma non so quanto sia "ufficialmente" un proverbio, *il cattivo artigiano incolpa agli attrezzi*. È esattamente equivalente all'inglese *it's a poor workman who blames his tools*. Si trova anche *l'artigiano incapace dà la colpa ai propri attrezzi*.

Comment: @lserni Anche questo è interessante, però è da notare che l'artigiano è responsabile dei suoi attrezzi, se li procura e li mantiene, mentre la lavandaia trova le pietre in natura e deve adeguarsi a una situazione preesistente, e questa è una situazione più vicina a quella di un lavoratore che deve adattarsi ad una strumentazione che gli viene messa a disposizione.